# how can i use event in owl-carousel

Tags: php, html, css, owl-carousel

I have three sliders in my webpage. I wrote an event for my second slider. but it gives this event to the first one. How can i give this event to the second one?

```php
$('#owl-three').on('.initialized.owl.carousel translate.owl.carousel', function(e){
idx = e.item.index;
$('.owl-item.big').removeClass('big');
$('.owl-item.medium').removeClass('medium');
$('.owl-item.dir').removeClass('dir');
$('.owl-item.small').removeClass('small');
$('.owl-item').eq(idx+3).addClass('medium');
$('.owl-item').eq(idx+1).addClass('medium');
$('.owl-item').eq(idx+2).addClass('big');
$('.owl-item').eq(idx).addClass('small');
$('.owl-item').eq(idx+4).addClass('small');
$('.owl-item').eq(idx+4).addClass('dir');


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your html like this

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="#owl-three">
    <div class="item" data-dot="1"><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div class="item" data-dot="2"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="item" data-dot="3"><h4>3</h4></div>
</div>
```

And use this script In this script you can do any thing as per desired slide by adding if condition I already add if condition for slide 2 you can write anything under that condition for slide 2

```
$('#owl-three').on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
     var currentSlide = $('div.active').find('.item').data('dot');
     if(currentSlide == 2) {
     }
 });
```